# Using Regular Expression how to remove if a certain character is at the end?

Tags: regex, iis-7.5, url-rewriting, rule

I am trying to write a URL rewriter rule in IIS7.
My current reg expression is `^(policy|pricing|contact|gallery)/(.*)`
My Rewrite rule is: `/{R:1}.aspx?cat={R:2}`

policy/         (Keep Slash in this case, WORKS)

gallery/soccer               (No slash provided so this WORKS)

gallery/soccer/              (needs to remove last slash)

gallery/soccer/girls/      (needs to remove last slash)

Any ideas would be great, I know how I would approach this in languages like .Net, but I need to strictly do this as a regular expression rule in IIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following should work:

```
^(policy|pricing|contact|gallery)/(.*?)/?$
```

The `/?` at the end means "match a `/` one or zero times", or in other words it is optional.  Just adding this to the end wouldn't work because a `/` would still be consumed by the `.*`, so we need to change the `.*` to `.*?` so that it is no longer greedy.

The `$` anchor is necessary so that the match doesn't end too early.

Note that the trailing `/` will still be a part of the match, but it will not be a part of the second capture group so your rewrite rule should work properly.

See it working: http://www.rubular.com/r/s8IqIlaqoz

Comment: @NYTom - No problem, you should [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/155356) that you think is best by clicking the outline of the check mark next to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

This might work

```
^(policy|pricing|contact|gallery)/([^/]*(?:/[^/]+)*)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you explicitly put it at the end (I have not escaped `/` because it looks like you're not doing so), you will effectively remove it in your re-write by not including that group.

```
^(policy|pricing|contact|gallery)/(.*)/?$
```

By adding `$` we are ensuring that only a final forward slash is removed -- there can still be *n* forward slashes in between.

Comment: I tried that thanks, the problem is its still including the / at the end because ? is 0 or more times. If I use + (1 or more time) it will remove the slash if its there but if the input string doesn't have the slash at the end, then it wont find a match because the + says 1 or more, so its like a catch 22 problem.